# Relation scalar product between vectors and sums of their components

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

Is there a relation between scalar product of two vectors
$$\sum_i a_i b_i$$
and sums of their components
$$ \sum_i a_i \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_i b_i$$????

Answer (score 2):

The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, while not offering a relation with the *sum* of the components, nevertheless gives a relation with the *sum of squares* of the components:

$$\big(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\big)^2\leq\big(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\big)\big(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2\big)$$

Comment: You could also write: $$\big(\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{a_ib_i}\big)^2\leq\big(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\big)\big(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i\big)$$